# User agent detection to include js file

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I'm trying to write some detection code. If user agent is iPad, then write this javascript but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript"
       src="photoswipe/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js"></script>');
  }
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Using user-agent sniffing is a bad idea, as is `document.write` (although I assume the latter is for debug only?)

Comment: Try breaking up the end script tag and concatenate it: </scr'+'ipt>'

Comment: </scr'+'ipt> did it. Thanks Robot Woods. @ beardtwizzle I don't know js very well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (from David Walsh's blog: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad) :

```
// For use within normal web clients 
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

// For use within iPad developer UIWebView
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_1_2/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_2_2/i.test(ua);
```

Using it:

```
if(isiPad){
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="photoswipe/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js"><\/script>');
}
```